# Android Studio "Refresh" fragment(s) layout from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

It's been a while, when I am trying to figure out my problem.

I want to "refresh" my fragments layout widgets, for example, textviews, imageviews, cardviews, and all other.

I'm trying to do this like:

`((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BCFrame)).setImageResource(R.drawable.frame_1_6);`

> But, it always shows, nullObjectPointer error(Becouse these for
>   example CardViews are in other layout.)

I have figured out, that I can refresh them, when I click somewhere in that fragment, with "onClick" function

```
  public void RefreshUpgrade(View view){
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerUpgradeTView)).setText("Player level: " +Main.PlayerLevel[0]);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.BoxUpgradeTView)).setText("Box level: " + Main.BoxesLevel[0]);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.GarageUpgradeTView)).setText("Garage level: " + Main.GarageLevel[0]);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.GarageSlotsTView)).setText("Garage slots: " + Main.GarageSlots[0]);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.short_description222)).setText("Money: " + Main.Money[0] + "/600");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.short_description22)).setText("Boxes Opened: " + Main.BoxesOpened[0] + "/30");

    if(Main.Money[0] >= 600){
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.short_description222)).setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
    }
}
```

But I need 2 things, that can't figure out.

1.I need these objects to "refresh" automatically, if arguments are true(if statements in MainActivity)

2.I need these objects to "refresh" automatically, after some time have went(Like GameLoop).

In Simple Java I got this all working, but there I got only JPanels, nothing like fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't search for the `Views` in your Activity that belong to the Fragment. In your `Fragment` class store them in varibles like e.g.

```
class Fragment
private TextView playerUpgradeTextView;

 public void refreshViews(){
 // your refreshUpgrade() method
}

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourFragmentLayout, container, false);
        playerUpgradeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.PlayerUpgradeTView)
        return v;
    }
```

Since your `Activity` holds your `Fragment` you can call the `refreshViews` method and pass it method parameters if needed.

Your second question is more a classic periodic event which also calls the `refreshViews` method.

Comment: @trakasi This is a different question, but does your `ClickerFragment` extend `Fragment`? Otherwise look into opening a new question.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is working, but got problem.. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.crelix.crelix.ClickerFragment.refreshViews()' on a null object reference

Comment: Yes it's extends, and in ClickerFragment method refreshViews are shown as "used" (Yellow color in Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to "rebuild" your fragment and forcing it to call `onCreateView`.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

For your auto refresh:

**Create a handler**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

**Create Runnable object**

```
public final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code to refresh
    }
};
```

**Call method of handler object**

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, yourdelay);
```